# Structured Data JSON ld in asp c#

Tags: c#, json

I am looking to add structure data script via json ld to a c# asp.net web application.

Here is the structured data script I am looking to add. I am getting runtime errors because of the @ conflict with c#: `The name 'context' does not exist in the current context`...this is obviously due to the @ syntax conflict.

What is an easy way to get around this?

> ```
> <script type="application/ld+json">
> {
> "@context": "http://schema.org",
> "@type": "LegalService",
> "image": "https://example.com.png",
> "@id": "https://example.com",
> "name": "Example Name",
> "description": "Example description.",
> "address": {
> "@type": "PostalAddress",
> "streetAddress": "Example Address",
> "addressLocality": "Example City",
> "addressRegion": "Example State",
> "postalCode": "Example Postal",
> "addressCountry": "Example Country"
> },
> "url": "https://example.com",
> "telephone": "Example number",
> "sameAs": [
> "example social account 1",
> "example social account 2"
> ]
> }
> </script>
> ```

So it looks like the way around this, thanks to @scartag, is to add a double @.

I am also trying to add a loop inside the script, but I'm getting runtime errors. I'm not sure if this is even possible. It is for blog articles that will be generated in the CMS.

See below:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@@type": "NewsArticle",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@@type": "WebPage",
    "@@id": "https://google.com/article"
  },
  @foreach (var post in recent)
    {
  "headline": "Article headline",
  "image": {
    "@@type": "ImageObject",
    "url": "https://google.com/thumbnail1.jpg",
    "height": 800,
    "width": 800
  },
  "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
  "dateModified": "2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00",
  "author": {
    "@@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
   "publisher": {
    "@@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Google",
    "logo": {
      "@@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://google.com/logo.jpg",
      "width": 600,
      "height": 60
    }
  },
  "description": "A most wonderful article"
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: your json is malformed....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After fixing the json (removing the redundant `]`) as pointed in the comments.

You can escape the `@` sign

```
"@@context": "http://schema.org",
```

Comment: So the way to get around this is to add a double @ sign for context, type, etc.?

Comment: @Bobi I guess so .. i haven't tried it for javascript but it works for html so i think it should work.

Comment: I 'm worried that this will negatively impact SEO ... not referencing the correct schema property syntax...

Comment: @Bobi SEO?? this will not be rendered on the resulting html page .. it's purely server side code. Try it and see what the result is.

Comment: @Bobi what i mean is, if it works it will only render one `@` and not the two you included.

Comment: Oh, ok...great @scartag ! Brilliant. This just saved me. Thanks! After running it on localhost, it all works correctly. Neat trick.

Comment: @scartag can you give some reference where this works in html.. just curious and want to learn..

Comment: @loneshark99 Lets say you want to include a twitter handle in razor code and wanted to avoid the error you'd say `<span>@@scartag</span>` it would render as @scartag without any errors.

Comment: @loneshark99 Just in case I wasn't clear from my first response, i didn't mean a raw html file but the html parts of a razor file (*.cshtml)

Comment: @scartag my bad... I thought it was breaking in the json because of @ sign. Yeah in C# makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @scartag do you know of a way to add a loop (for each statement) within the above script (i.e. for articles that are auto generated...when I add the for each statement in the above, i'm getting syntax errors.

Comment: @Bobi Maybe you could create a new question or modify your existing one to include the foreach you added and i'll take a look.

Comment: @Bobi You could try enclosing the body of the loop with `<text> content</text>` similar to `foreach(var post in recent) { <text> my json content </text> } `

Comment: @scartag I added another question regarding syntax, JSON, and c# here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625308/structured-data-issue-with-search-engine ... you seem to be the json c# expert ... any ideas?